# run button in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, background, xcode4, ios-simulator

Whenever I re-run my application by selecting the run button in xcode for, it says simulator already in use. So I have to stop it every time before re-running. 
So my question is, is there any option or setting to avoid this. I want to run the application without stopping it like we used to do in xcode 3.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that pressing the Home button, even in the simulator, does not stop your app under iOS 4. You can either stop your app in the debugger, or in the simulator, or you can modify your app such that it doesn't run in the background. See [Opting Out of Background Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW24).

Comment: Thanks for answering. This problem is not occurring for a particular application. Its occurring for all the application. Stopping the app to go in the background will not work here.

Comment: @iVipinS - By default, all applications support running in the background.  Unless you hard-kill them using the Xcode stop button, by terminating them in the multitasking interface on the Simulator, or by opting out of background execution, they will keep running if you hit the home button on the Simulator or device.  If one application is running in the background on the Simulator and you attempt to debug another, you won't be able to until the first is halted.

Answer (score 0):

In Application PLIST file, we have a flag of “Application does not run in background”.

If you set this flag to “YES” and press home button, application will not maintain its status or perform any background tasks.

Answer (score -2):

This is a bug in Xcode 4 which occurs sometimes. Usually you can make it go away by quitting the Simulator and restarting Xcode. If that still doesn't fix the problem, I would report the issue at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com/) and see if the engineers at Apple can help.